# Is there a Python equivalent to QGIS Raster Calculator's "file1.asc" AND "file2.asc"

Tags: qgis, python, raster, raster-calculator

I would like to script a calculation equivalent to QGIS Raster Calculator's

"file1.asc" AND "file2.asc".

I have 18 data raster files which I would like to do the equivalent of ADD to each of five other rasters.

Is there an easy way to script (Python?) this that will take me less time than ploughing through it in Qgis?

Comment: ADD or AND is the question (for me), so does QGIS Raster Calculator's AND do a concat or is it some kind of a uniqueness also (duplicates removed)? Sorry did not work with QGIS in a while ... maybe other Pythonistas could more easily help, when knowing what the operation shall result in.

Comment: The output file only shows a pixel value 1 where _both_ input values were 1.
Does that make sense?